# Calling functions from runnable

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a piece of code in an Android application, that is an implementation of Runnable.
in my implementation of the method `void run()` I've called a function within the Activity itself, outside the Runnable implementation.

The code looks as follows:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain(null, Communicator.MSG_REFRESH_ASSIGNED_LOCATIONS, 
      new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Cursor assignedLocations = getAssignedLocations();
            assignedLocations.moveToFirst(); //EXCEPTION HERE! NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!!
            if(!assignedLocations.isAfterLast()) {
                //some code
            } else {
                //some code
            }
        }
});
```

The function is `getAssignedLocations()` and it returns a Cursor from a query to the sqlite.

The `getAssignedLocations()` function works and does not return null when called from outside the implementation of Runnable (meaning from onResume or onCreate).

Here is the code for `getAssignedLocations()`:

```
/**
 * returns a cursor for all assigned locations in the local database
 * @return
 */
protected Cursor getAssignedLocations() {
    return getAssignedLocations(null);
}

/**
 * returns a cursor from the database with only one entry of which the loc_id is specificLoaction
 * if specificLocation is null, returns all assigned locations from the database
 * @param specificLocation
 * @return
 */
private Cursor getAssignedLocations(String specificLocation) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = personalLocations.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {
            FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOC_ID,
            FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOC_NAME
    };

    String orderBy = 
            FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOC_NAME + " DESC";

    if(specificLocation == null) {
        Cursor c = db.query(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
        return c;
    }

    String[] arguments = {specificLocation};

    Cursor c = db.query(FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_LOC_ID + "=?", arguments, null, null, orderBy);
    return c;
}
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a null pointer exception? Is passing a non static function to the Runnable interface does not suppose to work?

Comment: As I said, the function works okay when calling directly from onResume of the activity.

Comment: it might be helpful to see the `getAssignedLocations()` function. keep in mind that when you call `getAssignedLocations()` within the runnable, you are likely executing in a thread other than the main UI thread, so `getAssignedLocations()` should be a threadsafe function.

Comment: I will add the code for `getAssignedLocations()` now. Also, I'm afraid I don't know what a threadsafe function is. can you explain?

Comment: @Tom How are you executing your `Runnable`?

Comment: Is your `Runnable` being sent to a Handler bound to the UI thread (main thread) of your Activity?

Comment: Tom, in very general terms a function is thread-safe if it works as expected while being called simultaneously from different threads. In practice, if you have a function that changes some state or shared data, it is likely that it may not behave as you intended when being called from within multiple threads. In this case, if `getAssignedLocations()` is being called on a different thread, `personalLocations` could be the shared data of interest. Where is that declared?

Comment: the `personalLocations` you see at the beginning is an field of the activity, of Class `PersonalLocationsDbHelper` instansiated from `onCreate()` like so: `personalLocations = new PersonalLocationsDbHelper(getApplicationContext());`. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I'm sending it to a service, that service has need to run another Async Task, when all is done and ready, there is a call for `msg.getCallback().run()`.

Comment: Yes. I'm not an android person, but I believe onCreate() occurs on the UI thread and I'm also guessing the database query is running on another. How many other places reference that `personalLocations` object?

Comment: tried what you suggested (you were talking about the definition of the methods in lines 5 and 15, right?), unfortunately there is no change in the outcome whatsoever. :-(

Comment: `Message.obtain(...)`, is that also called in `onCreate()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56673/discussion-between-sethro-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to much help from sethro, we have figured out together that the mistake was in another part of the code not even included in the question.

I've used the wrong Message.obtain method and therefor placed the Runnable implementation in Message.obj instead of Message.getCallback(). So when I called it to get the Runnable in the service, it returned null. The null pointer exception was actually from there.

For future comers, this is probably something to note to be careful of, when you use message.obtain. Some of its variation accepts `Object` and therefor will not warn you when you place the wrong paramater there.

C++ programmers will probably laugh at us for having trouble with it :-)